# Xcode 4.3.1 iPad Simulator Changes related to screen size and multitouch

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've noticed a few weird things about the simulator in Xcode 4.3.1.

1) The simulator is now too big to fit on my screen and I have to scroll up and down while testing my App. I have a 13" Macbook and it used to resize it to fit my screen which was much more convenient.

2) Option clicking used to allow me to test multitouch gestures but it does not do anything in the simulator after installing 4.3.1. I can still test multitouch gestures in the iPhone simulator though.

Any help or insight into these two issues would be appreciated. Is it just me experiencing this or is it a common issue. Is what I am experiencing a bug or a "feature"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same here on my old Macbook, I had to go to Window->Scale: 50% and now it's reasonable.

Comment: is right about this. I suspect your settings were just reset somehow, but this is a feature of the simulator that has been around for a while.

Comment: Oh nice I was looking for some way to scale it but I didn't notice that option last night. Yeah it did seem to get reset somehow but now it's back to the behavior I expect and multitouch works again.

I should add that it does look a bit different now, there's no border that it used to have, but that is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

As iPad Simulator does not auto-rotate on default, I'll just add this: Also make sure to simulate rotation for iPad Simulator, to get iPad display to fit horziontal: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> & <kbd>→</kbd> (or <kbd>←</kbd>).